# Problema mysqli PHP: Acces denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy teniendo un problema al hacer una prueba con un código en PHP en mi servidor.
El código sería:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && is_numeric($_POST["id"])) {
$id=$_POST["id"];
}
else {
$id=1;
}
$mysqli = new mysqli('[IP de mi servidor]', 'root', '[mi contraseña]', '[mi DB]');
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
die("Conexión con el servidor fallida (" . $mysqli->connect_error . ").");
}
?>
```

Hay más código después, pero el error que se ejecuta es ese.

He probado a incluir la IP en el usuario (root@[mi IP]), a reiniciar el servidor, etc., y sigo teniendo el error

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Sin embargo, si entro desde PuTTY a MySQL con el usuario root y la misma contraseña, tengo acceso total.

Comment: algún caracter especial en la contraseña que necesite ser escapado en la cadena de php?

Comment: @HammerffallBK , - _ # alguno de esos?

Comment: ¿Con otro usuario distinto conecta?

Comment: Desde putty como te conectas, usas una ip en específico o como 127.0.0.1, puede que ahi este el problema

Comment: @HammerffallBK sí, pero no sé donde podría estar ahí el error

Comment: Si desde putty y tu script estas utilizando la misma ip o dirección, si es curioso que no funcione, si son distitntas en putty y el script, puede que la que utilizas en el script no tenga el acceso que esperas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El còdigo como tal no se ve que tenga errores, lo que me llama la atenciòn es que en el paràmetro de configuraciòn escribes "IP de mi servidor" cuando deberìa ser ( en el 99% de los casos) "localhost". Si eso no llegara a funcionar, y suponiendo que usas cPanel, debes crear un usuario con password y posteriormente asignarlo a tu base de datos, puedes probar entrar a phpmyadmin, si logras logearte con las credenciales que te comentè que debes crear, entonces muy seguramente resolveràs tu issue.

Comment: Ah o sea, si el archivo está en el propio servidor, debo usar siempre localhost en vez de la IP?

Comment: Si, es correcto... en raras ocasiones debes usar la IP o alguna otra URL que tu proveedor te indique.

Answer (score 2):

el error te esta indicando que no tienes acceso, ya que estas incluyendo contraseña y tu servidor no tiene contraseña, cuando no la tiene solo debería quedar así:

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "base_datos");
```

las comillas que dejo vacías son de la contraseña por que al no tenerla no debo escribir algo ahí.

Por el contrario si si tienes contraseña de acceso debería quedar así:

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "clave_secreta", "base_datos");
```

clave_secreta = a la contraseña que tienes asignada, checa que este bien escrita
base_datos = nombre de la base de datos igual checa que el nombre este bien escrito

Si por ejemplo el servidor esta en tu propia computadora entonces es localhost, si esta en un servidor externo entonces va la IP que te sea asignada y la checas desde cPanel

Y el orden es: servidor, usuario, contraseña y base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el usuario y dale privilegios

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
flush privileges;
```